# Remove New Relic .NET Agent RUM code from a specific request

Tags: .net, newrelic

We are using the .NET version of New Relic. It appears as though upon output, New Relic parses the output to see if it contains any `</head>` elements and inserts its `<script type="text/javascript">var NREUMQ=...` script before it.

My problem is that on a particular closed source page there is a line of js that reads...

```
document.write("<html><head></head><body></body></html>");
```

...New Relic then turns this into...

```
document.write("<html><head><script type="text/javascript">var NREUMQ=NREUMQ||[];NREUMQ.push(["mark","firstbyte",new Date().getTime()]);</script></head><body></body></html>");
```

...which causes major headaches as the New Relic code is not escaped.

What I would like to do is somehow tell New Relic to not inject the code on this particular page as I cannot edit the page.

Cheers!

Here is the modified code in pretty format - for your viewing pleasure (not what is actually in the response)....

```
document.write("<html><head><script type="text/javascript">
                var NREUMQ=NREUMQ||[];
                NREUMQ.push(["mark","firstbyte",new Date().getTime()]);
                </script></head><body></body></html>");
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**EDIT 2017-01-25**
(new urls)

- https://docs.newrelic.com/docs/agents/net-agent/net-agent-api/disablebrowsermonitoring-net-agent
- https://docs.newrelic.com/docs/agents/net-agent/net-agent-api/getbrowsertimingheader-net-agent

---

**ORIGINAL POST**
I have received an answer from New Relic support. Here it is...

> Hello Michael,
>
> This is a fantastic question! There is a very direct way of
>   accomplishing what you want to do.
>
> The .Net Agent injects snippets of javascript into the header and
>   footer of pages sent to the users browser to measure the page load
>   time on the user's end. We call this feature Real User Monitoring or
>   RUM for short. More info about that is here:
>   https://newrelic.com/docs/features/how-does-real-user-monitoring-work
>
> If you wish to completely disable RUM on all pages you can edit
>   `newrelic.config` and change this line:
>
> ```
> <browserMonitoring autoInstrument="true"/>
> ```
>
> to this:
>
> ```
> <browserMonitoring autoInstrument="false"/>
> ```
>
> You can disable RUM on individual pages and/or manually specify where
>   the RUM header/footer snippets are injected into the page by using the
>   .Net Agent API calls. To use this library, add a reference to
>   NewRelic.Api.Agent.dll to your project. The DLL should be found in
>   this folder: `"%ProgramFiles%\New Relic\.NET Agent"`
>
> Then you can disable the RUM on specific pages using this API call:
>
> - https://newrelic.com/docs/dotnet/the-net-agent-api#disable_browser
>
> Or you can manually inject the header and foot where you would like
>   them to be using these API calls:
>
> - https://newrelic.com/docs/dotnet/the-net-agent-api#timing_header
> - https://newrelic.com/docs/dotnet/the-net-agent-api#timing_footer

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same problem today. I was able to fix it by having the Javascript combine "he" and "ad" on the client. This prevents the New Relic RUM from seeing a HEAD tag.

`document.write("<html><he" + "ad></he" + "ad><body></body></html>");`

Comment: Yeah, that's what I wanted to do but the code that generates the `document.write` is a closed source third party binary. :S

Comment: Ah, that definitely complicates matters. I guess you could override document.write and add the necessary code to break up the head tag, but the best answer is probably to just disable the automatic injection as suggested above.

Answer (score 0):

I just want to add to Gerrard's answer .. his solution worked for me but I also had to break up the BODY tag .. New Relic was thoughtful enough to add it's own HEAD tag before my BODY tag after it couldn't detect my original HEAD tag.

As a side note - this auto instrumentation has caused me a lot of pain in multiple projects.

Comment: Ha! I actually did break up the body tag as well in my code just to be safe. I removed it from the example I shared, because I didn't think it was necessary. Please feel free to edit my answer!

Answer (score 0):

There's actually a much simpler solution to this problem adding one line of code to your cshtml or aspx file:

```
NewRelic.Api.Agent.NewRelic.DisableBrowserMonitoring();
```

Comment: This is all well and good if you have access to add server-side code to the page..